# How can I perform a substitutions on multiple variables whose names I don't know ahead of time?

Tags: perl, variables, configuration-files

I'm working on a Perl script where the user adds a number of set variables at the beginning of the script, all prefixed with `$XX`, as seen below. The user-set variables, however, need to go through a short transformation function to clean them up.

Is there a way to run the sub on all the variables with the `$XX` prefix?

```
my $XXvar1 = "something";
my $XXvar2 = "something";
my $XXvar3 = "something";
my $XXvar4 = "something";

sub processVar {
    my $fixVar = $_[0];
    # Do stuff
    return $fixVar;
}

# This obviously doesn't work. Use some kind of loop or something? How...
$XXvar* = processVar($XXvar*);
```

**Edit:**
I'm trying to do this now with a hash, as per some suggestions on Google:

```
my %XX;

$XX{var1} = "something 1";
$XX{var2} = "something 2";
$XX{var3} = "something 3";
$XX{var4} = "something 4";
```

I can then work with the keys and values in `for` or `while` loops. However, how can I reassign each variable to the transformed one in the loop?

**Edit again:**
Got it. This `for` loop processes all the variables successfully:

```
for my $key ( keys %XX ) {
    $XX{$key} = processVar($XX{$key});
}
```

I'm definitely going to try to make a configuration file now, though, as suggested below. Now I just have to figure that out :)

Comment: See also the map function http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/functions/map.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of users editing the source and providing odd variable names, use a configuration file instead. Every user can get his own configuration file. There are several modules on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) to handle configuration files of just about any format, and I talk about ways to configure Perl programs in a chapter of [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242). It's certainly a lot easier than the tricks you'd need to do to magically pick up these variable names.

Comment: yeah, having configuration files in the source itself is kinda wonky.
http://search.cpan.org/search?query=ini&mode=all

Comment: here's link to a modified version for that chapter http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/11.configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

Read MJD's:

1. [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)
2. [Part 2](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html)
3. [Part 3](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html)

Comment: Yet another proof that comments should be editable. (As is, you can only delete and then add another. But if I did that here, my comment would be under your response, and that wouldn't make any damn sense. So my typo remains forever. Feh.)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $XXvar1 = "something";
my $XXvar2 = "something";
my $XXvar3 = "something";
my $XXvar4 = "something";

my @values;
for ( 1 .. 4 ) {
    push @values, eval '$XXvar' . $_;
}

processVar(@values);

sub processVar {
    print "@_";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it. But don't do this it's evil :-)

```
use PadWalker qw(peek_my peek_our peek_sub closed_over);
my $XXvar1 = "something1a";
my $XXvar2 = "something2b";
my $XXvar3 = "something3c";
my $XXvar4 = "something4d";
my $noXXvar = "something5e";

#remove last character
sub clean {
  my $h = peek_my(1);
  while(my ($key, $value) = each(%$h)) {
    if ($key =~ /^\$XXvar.+/) {
       chop ${$h->{$key}}
    }
  }
}
clean();

print "$XXvar1\n";  //something1
print "$XXvar2\n";  //something2
print "$XXvar3\n";  //something3
print "$XXvar4\n";  //something4
print "$noXXvar\n"; //something5e
```

My Perl is a bit rusty so there surly is a shorter/cleaner version of it.